# URL::assets Laravel 5.2.29

Tags: laravel-5

I want to call all my `css` and `js` files using `UR::asset`
but the **problem** is it returns this output **"Method does not exist."**

My code:

```
 <link href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/style.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use public_path() method for this.
i.e

public_path('css/style.css');

Here is laravel documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-public-path)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't have any typos in your code: `URL::asset()`. I would also suggest using the helper function `asset()` instead for brevity.